# How do i get the bounded/margin support vectors in sklearn.SVR

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I have an epsilon-SVR model in which I trained, with a specific epsilon of say 0.001.
I get the following output,

```
[LibSVM]*.*

optimization finished, #iter = 69

obj = -0.032164, rho = 0.006072

nSV = 11, nBSV = 4
```

From the output I know that 4 of my support vectors are bounded i.e. lay on the margin.

Now the answer is simple of course, just

`numpy.argwhere(svr_model.predict(svr_model.support_vectors) == svr_model.epsilon)`

Or possibly

`numpy.argwhere(trainY(svr_model.support_) == svr_model.epsilon)`

Yet either way I return none. I understand that it is to do with the decimal points that come after the predictions but what is the tolerance for this?

Am I even doing this right?